# ERROR while running phonegap application on Genymotion

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, genymotion

I am newbie to phonegap development please help me. I have 3 html files in my application. In config.xml I mentioned like this

```
content src="index.html"
```

while executing my app on genymotion index.html file is executing, but from index.html it has to redirect to another html page(ex:screen2.html) but second screen is not executing it is showing error like

> NET://ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(home//app//www/screen2.html).

But on browser my application is executing.